# My contact form creates an unwanted margin when switched to mobile version

Tags: html, css

i have a contact form on my main page on top of an image slider that looks like this :

[image]

The form is inside of slider's div like this :

```
<div class="img-slide">

<div class="img fade">
<img src="#">
</div>

<div class="contact-form">
</div>

</div>
```

When i switch to my mobile version on Chrome, it first looks like this , and then when i refresh everything is fine .

[image]

If i remove the form everything is fine so i know for sure the margin is created by it.

Here is the CSS code for the web version and the mobile version .

```
**This is the web version**

.img-slide .contact-form {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 40px;
height: 320px;
width: 310px;
background-color: #d1cfcf;
text-align: center;
}




***This is the mobile version***

@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {

.img-slide .contact-form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position:unset;
    margin:0;
}
}
```

Comment: did you used  CSS media query for mobile ?

Comment: yes ,@media only screen and (max-width: 415px)

Comment: than you have to provide that

Comment: sorry i did now

Comment: if there is extra margin is there than you have to use `margin:0px` in your mobile view

Comment: i've tried it doesn't work

Comment: it's difficult to figure out where is problem can you provide some run able snippet

Comment: I face this problem when width of some section of my website is wider. specially footer section. please check wherever you use class 'row'.

Comment: that's the first thing i checked , if i refresh the page once it's fine , onlt the first time it pops up like that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `position: unset` `position: relative` ? Also, have you played with the width?

Comment: Could you add a snippet or a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys i think it's just a bug from the browser . In code pen is fine